# when i run a code for playing basket ball the ball doesnt move it bring up an attribute error

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

```
'''
GUI controller for Basket Ball
Created Sprint 2015
@author: Bfm2'''


import math
from tkinter import *
# from ballofical import *



# def distance(x, y, x1, y1):
#     return ((x - x1) ** 2 + (y - y1) ** 2)**0.5

class Frame1():
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Basket Ball")

        frame=Frame(window)
        frame.pack()

        Button(frame, text='shoot',command = self.move(280, 640,30,30,50)).grid(row=1, column=1)   #command = with time class work on shot measurement 
        Button(frame, text = "+speed").grid(row=1,column=2)  #command = with time class work on shot measurement 
        Button(frame, text = "-speed").grid(row= 1, column=3)  #command = with time class work on shot measurement
        Button(frame, text = "+angle").grid(row=1, column=4)   #command = with time class work on shot measurement 
        Button(frame, text = "-angle").grid(row= 1, column=5)  #command = with time class work on shot measurement

        frame1=Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()

        self.canvas = Canvas(frame1, width = 1080, height = 820, bg = 'white')
        self.canvas.pack()

#         photo=PhotoImage(file="Carmelo_Anthony_free_throw.png")
#         label=Label(frame1, image = photo)
#         label.pack()

        self.canvas.create_polygon(0, 810, 
                                   1080, 810, 
                                   1080, 450, 
                                   150, 450,  
                                   fill="grey") 

        self.canvas.create_polygon(150, 0, 
                                   1080, 0, 
                                   1080, 450, 
                                   150, 450,  
                                   fill="green") 

        self.canvas.create_polygon(0, 0, 
                                   0, 810, 
                                   150, 450, 
                                   150, 0,  
                                   fill="red") 

        self.canvas.create_oval(780, 97, 
                                850, 80, 
                                tags = 'rim')

        self.canvas.create_line(855, 105, 
                                855, 20, width = 3, 
                                tags='Board')

        self.canvas.create_line(990, 90, 
                                1080, 10, width = 3,) 

        self.canvas.create_line(850, 90, 
                                990, 90, width = 3, 
                                tags='pole')

        self.canvas.create_line(1080, 720, 
                                300, 720, width = 3, 
                                tags='GL1')

        self.canvas.create_line(1080, 520, 
                                300, 520, width = 3, 
                                tags='GL2')



        self.canvas.create_line(300, 720, 
                                300, 520, width = 3, 
                                tags='GL3')

        self.canvas.create_line(150, 0, 
                                150, 450, width = 8, 
                                tags='GL3')

        self.canvas.create_line(1080, 810, 
                                0, 810, width = 8, 
                                tags='GL1')

        self.canvas.create_line(0, 810, 
                                150, 450, width = 8, 
                                tags='GL3')

        self.canvas.create_line(1080, 450, 
                                150, 450, width = 8, 
                                tags='GL1')

        self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 
                                0, 810, width = 5, 
                                tags='GL1')

        self.canvas.create_oval(280, 640, 
                                240, 600, width = 3,fill = "brown",
                                tags = 'Ball X,Y')    

        window.mainloop()

    def move(self,x,y,velx,vely,size):
        self.x=x
        self.y=x
        self.velx=velx
        self.vely=vely
        self.size=size
        self.angle=0
        self.x += math.sin(self.angle) * self.velx
        self.y -= math.cos(self.angle) * self.vely  

        if self.x + self.size > self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth():
            self.speed = -self.speed #negate x velocity
        if self.x - self.size < 0:
            self.speed = -self.speed #negate x velocity
        if self.y + self.size > self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth():
            self.speed = -self.speed #negate y velocity
        if self.y - self.size< 0:
            self.speed = -self.speed #negate y velocity      




Frame1()
```

on the consol this pops up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bfm2/workspace/cs108/src/projecttake2/frame.py", line 140, in <module>
    Frame1()
  File "/home/bfm2/workspace/cs108/src/projecttake2/frame.py", line 29, in __init__
    Button(frame, text='shoot',command = self.move(280, 640,30,30,50)).grid(row=1, column=1)   #command = with time class work on shot measurement 
  File "/home/bfm2/workspace/cs108/src/projecttake2/frame.py", line 128, in move
    if self.x + self.size > self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth():
AttributeError: 'Frame1' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

i need help im not understanding whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Button(frame, text='shoot',command = self.move(280,640,30,30,50))` you mean to bind a call to `self.move(280,640,30,30,50)`, but you are binding the return function of that call (which is `None`) to the button click. To find the return function, `self.move` is called upon the Button initiation, before the canvas is created.

You could wrap the call to `self.move(280,640,30,30,50)` in an anonymous lambda function (`command = lambda: self.move(280,640,30,30,50)`), but I'm guessing you are going to get (some of) the arguments from other variables later, which might make it more useful to create an actual intermediate function that takes no arguments but gets the values to pass to `self.move` and calls that like:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    Button(frame, text='shoot',command = self.callback).grid(row=1, column=1)
    # Note there is no () after self.callback, it's a function reference not a function call
    ...

def callback(self):
    x    = 280 # Or get a value from somewhere
    y    = 640
    velx = 30
    vely = 30
    size = 50
    self.move(x, y, velx, vely, size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Frame1`'s `__init__` method, you're calling `self.move`, which uses `self.canvas`, before `self.canvas` has been defined.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you are calling the method `self.move()` on this line:

```
Button(frame, text='shoot',command = self.move(280, 640,30,30,50)).grid(row=1, column=1)`
```

before you define `self.canvas`, but `self.move()` requires `self.canvas`, so move this line:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(frame1, width = 1080, height = 820, bg = 'white')
```

above that Button instantiation.

You will notice that the `Canvas` instantiation takes `frame1` as its first argument, but if you move this line above the `Button` instantiation, `frame1` will no longer be defined. You will need to move both definitions above the `Button` instantiations like this:

```
frame1=Frame(window)
self.canvas = Canvas(frame1, width = 1080, height = 820, bg = 'white')
Button(frame, text='shoot',command = self.move(280, 640,30,30,50)).grid(row=1, column=1)
# ...
```

Comment: That's not really the problem. The real problem is that the code is calling `self.move` at the time the button is created rather than when it is clicked.